# Linux: Bash: what does mkdir return

Tags: linux, bash, mkdir

I want to write a simple check upon running mkdir to create a dir. First it will check whether the dir already exists, if it does, it will just skip. If the dir doesn't exist, it will run mkdir, if mkdir fails (meaning the script could not create the dir because it does not have sufficient privileges), it will terminate.

This is what I wrote:

```
if [ ! -d "$FINALPATH" ]; then
    if [[ `mkdir -p "$FINALPATH"` -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "\nCannot create folder at $FOLDERPATH. Dying ..."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

However, the 2nd if doesn't seem to be working right (I am catching 0 as return value for a successful mkdir). So how to correctly write the 2nd if? and what does mkdir returns upon success as well as failure?

Comment: Your answers didn't explicitly call you out on this but of course `mkdir -p` already checks that the directory exists, so you don't need to do your own check.

Comment: Oh... That's true ... I totally forgot about that.

Comment: As an aside, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form; all-caps names are reserved for variables created or used by system-provided tools. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The result of running

```
`mkdir -p "$FINALPATH"`
```

isn't the return code, but the output from the program. `$?` the return code. So you could do

```
if mkdir -p "$FINALPATH" ; then
    # success
else
    echo Failure
fi
```

or

```
mkdir -p "$FINALPATH"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo Failure
fi
```

Comment: Cool! It's working. One side question: what is the difference between `if [ condition ]; then` and `if [ condition ] \n then`? I don't quite get that part :(

Comment: @Tanner I think it's just stylistic.

Comment: @Tanner: It's just like any other context where you can have either a semicolon or a newline.  `command1 ; command2` is like `command1 \n command2` (I wish I could do real newlines in a comment!).  The word `then` has to be at the beginning of a line or following a `;` to be recognized; otherwise it's just a word (as in `echo then`).

Comment: I'm not sure an empty `if` statement body is actually legal in all shells (actually, I'm quite certain that it's not). You might need to make it something like `: success` or `true # success`... or just invert the test and not have an `else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

The shorter way would be

```
 mkdir -p "$FINALPATH" || echo failure
```

also idiomatic:

```
 if mkdir -p "$FINALPATH"
 then
      # .....
 fi
```

Likewise you can `while .....; do ....; done` or `until ......; do ......; done`

Comment: Needs more quotes -- the OP's code is safe for directory names with whitespace or wildcard characters; should be so here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you can exit by issuing:

```
mkdir -p "$FINALPATH" || { echo "Failure, aborting..." ; exit 1 ; }
```

Braces are necessary, or else `exit 1` would execute in both cases.

Or you can create an abort function like:

```
errormsg()
{
    echo "$1"
    echo Aborting...
    { exit 1 ; }
}
```

And then just call it by issuing:

```
mkdir -p "$FINALPATH" || errormsg "Failure creating $FINALPATH"
```

Edited:

- Braces, not parenthesis, as parenthesis only exit the subshell. 
  ( Thanks @Charles Duffy )
- A function to write a message and exit

Comment: If the goal is to exit the interpreter for the parent script, you want **braces**, not parens: `mkdir -p "$FINALPATH" || { echo "Failure, aborting..."; exit 1; }` -- mind the trailing `;`, it's mandatory if you don't have a newline there; without it, `}` is parsed as an argument to `exit`.